# How to use WebSocket to build a backend with Next.js

Tags: typescript, next.js, websocket

I want to build a backend using Next.js and try to use WebSocket in it.

Some helpful tutorials teaching you use 'socket.io' have been nearly outdate. One of them is this: [Implementing WebSocket communication in Next.js](https://blog.logrocket.com/implementing-websocket-communication-next-js/) , `rep.socket.server` isn't accessible any more.